# Explicit solution to a singular linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, closed-form

A quadratic optimization problem I have leads to a system of linear equations which I want to solve explicitly (with a closed formula). We are searching for $(s_{1},s_{2},s_{3},...,s_{N})$ such that

$$As=x$$
where $A$ is an $N\times N$ band (pentadiagonal) symmetric matrix
\begin{equation*}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0& \dots  &0 &0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 
-1 & 3 & -1 & -1  &0 &0& 0& \dots &0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0  \\\\
-1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0& \dots & 0&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 
0 & -1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 &0&\dots  & 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots &  & & & & & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots  \\\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& \dots &  -1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& \dots & 0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1  \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& \dots & 0 & 0 &-1 & -1   & 2  \\\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The sum of lines (or equivalently the sum of columns) of this matrix is $0$.
The diagnoal is of the form $(2,3,4,4,4,....,4,4,4,3,2)$ (length of $N$ where $N$ is greater than 10).

$x$ is a vector whose sum of components is $0$.

The system is singular and we know we can set $s_{1}=0$. We are actually only interested to express $s_{i}-s_{j}$ $(i,j=1,...,N)$as a function of the components of $x$ with a closed formula.

Is there are closed form solution for the $s_{i}-s_{j}$?

I have tried to stepwise solve the system but it is getting quite complex, I wonder if there is not a smarter way to get to a closed formula.